# Why doesn't addAll() support the addition of a collection's copy to the collection?

Tags: java, collections, set

In a method, I make two calls. The first call constructs and returns a hashset from another method. The second call adds this newly constructed set to an existing one, passed in as a parameter to this method.

```
public static void someMethod(java.util.HashSet<Coordinate> invalidPositions)
{
    java.util.HashSet<Coordinate> newSet = SomeClass.getInvalidPositions(x, y);
    invalidPositions.addAll(newSet);
}
```

Often times, the passed in set, the pre-existing one, will add another set whose contents are the same as itself! That is, `setOne.equals(setTwo) == true`

Instead of adding the other set, however, the JavaDocs say of `addAll()`:

> public boolean addAll(Collection c)
>
> Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection (optional operation).
>   The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (T*his implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection **is this collection**, and this collection is nonempty.*)

Have I understood this correctly? If two sets are equal, java will not support one's addition of the other? If this is true, is there any reason to design the language in this way?

Comment: person A can step on person B's shoulder to get higher. but A cannot step on A's shoulder to get higher. the assumption is that B is stationary; the operation does not change B's state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.equals(b)` is different from `a == b`.

What the javadoc means is that the behavior is undefined if you do `a.addAll(a)`. There is no problem in doing `a.addAll(b)` as long as they are different instances.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know why `a.addAll(a)` is problematic though?

Comment: @Muno Because as the javadoc says: "The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress". If you do `a.addAll(a)` it starts adding elements to `a`, which in this case is also the "specified collection" mentioned by the javadoc. In other words, you would be adding elements from a collection that is currently being changed. Besides, adding a collection to itself might create an infinite loop (depending on the type of the collection).